# Unable to add WPF controls to the toolbox in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, toolbox

First of all, I am completely new to Visual Studio, so please don't be too judgmental. I have a project I need to do in C# for my studies and my team uses a GitHub repository. I am in charge of creating the GUI and I am stuck at the very beggining.

I want to create the main application window using WPF, but when I use `toolbox` > `choose items`, I can not see the WPF tab. Also, when I am trying to enable the designer view, nothing happens.

Is it perhaps the software version being Visual Studio Community 2013 causing the issue? Do I need to have the Visual Studio Professional version in order to use WPF toolbox?

I'm attaching a link to the screen of the situation below.

[image: VS 2013 issue Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I presumed, all I needed was the professional version of Visual Studio. After obtaining and installing it everything works fine.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the accepted one. That way it stops showing up as not-accepted :)